# Switching users using WinSCP between different accounts

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sudo, winscp

Is there way to switch between user accounts using WinSCP?

When I am using PuTTY, I can use  `su` command to switch users between different accounts.

For an example:

```
kitis@localhost$
kitis@localhost$ su abc
abc@localhost$
```

In the same way, when I am using WinSCP, is there a way for me to switch users while I have logged in to a server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a FAQ for this question on WinSCP site:
[How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

You need to specify the `sudo` command in WinSCP session settings, as custom shell (if you are using SCP) or use `sudo` in custom SFTP server startup command (if you are using SFTP).

Though there are some limitations, notably that you need to configure `sudo` not to require a password.

See the link for details.

Answer (score 2):

If the user has sudo to another user via SSH.
The same sudo to another user works via WinSCP following the below settings.
In File Protocol select SCP, pass the hostname, username, and password/key and in advanced settings under **SCP/Shell** in Shell pass the value as **/usr/bin/sudo -u username -i**, click on ok and save the settings.
Now in Winscp, the user is logged in as the username provided in SCP/Shell.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible. When you want to switch user using SCP (WinSCP in your case) your need to relogin. You can't run any commands in SCP-session, just manage files; fnd SCP-protocol itself supports no mechanisms to change current users' id. You must use SSH if you want to have a possibility to change a user in a session.

Comment: This not really true. SCP protocol actually supports only transferring of files only, no "managing". On the other hand WinSCP is not really SCP client, so in fact it may allow using `su` command technically speaking (it does not though). And in fact, most people use WinSCP with SFTP, not SCP and that's a completely different story.