# How to access as root with WinSCP to Debian 8 server

Tags: debian, sftp, winscp

Since direct login as root is not permitted in debian 8, how can I switch to root or log as root ?

Comment: Off-topic. Anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11464824/850848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to login to sftp via password as root, and not with rsa key edit

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and change line

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

to

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Comment: How is this offtopic? there are tags debian sftp winscp, the topic is about them, guy asked question and i answer them instead being rude. If someone think it's wrong section, just move it to good one. Not everyone know how it's done from beginning.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Well isn't stack used to ask question not only about programming, but also installing and configuring?

Comment: Only if it is about installing/configuring tools specifically used for programming only. And this question is not about that.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic